# rethinkdb nodejs container in cluster environment

Tags: node.js, express, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

rethinkdb and nodejs+express app fit well in container for cluster environment??

The situation is below in a docker container
1. Running rethinkdb and nodjs+express app in one container
2. During the boot up of nodejs app it checks if there is a specific database and table exist or not. if not then create database and table

Running in one docker container works fine. But the problem is we need to do clustering of rethinkdb as well as maintaining specific number of replicas of the table.

putting all those clustering and replicas logic in the nodejs app seems not a good idea. Kind of stuck how can I proceed. 
Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Running rethinkdb and nodjs+express app in one container

You should typically not do this. Put `rethinkdb` in it's own container and put your application in a separate container.

I'd recommend using `docker-compose` and setup a `docker-compose.yml` file for your service. Make sure to use the `depends_on` property on the web application declaration so that `docker` will startup the `rethinkdb` container before the application container.

If you're hand spinning up your RethinkDB containers you should be totally set, but if you're using Swarm or some other scheduler, continue reading.

One problem RethinkDB has currently with automated / scheduled / containerized environments are ephemerality of containers and the possibility that they will possibly restart and come back with a different IP address. This requires some additional tooling around RethinkDB to modify the config tables.

For a bit of reading I'd recommend checking out [how this was achieved in Kubernetes](https://github.com/rosskukulinski/kubernetes-rethinkdb-cluster).

Comment: we are trying to follow micro-service architecture so we put everything in one container for a service. We are new micro-service architecture environment so not sure what is the best practice.

Comment: I'm confident this is the opposite of what you want, check out this article which explains why: http://microservices.io/patterns/deployment/service-per-container.html

Comment: Thanks dalanmiller, It also says separate database for each service is possible. http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html
we have one container with one rethinkdb and one nodejs express app.

Comment: If this were a VM with some sort of block storage attached we were talking about, I'd agree to run both services on the same instance. But with containers, it's really not recommended to run multiple services. Breaking it out allows you to use CPU and RAM more efficiently since you can scale each service (whether it be a database, application, or utility like redis) independently of one another. Putting everything in one container, limits your scaling effectiveness. Once your system gets more load, you want to scale up uniquely the services that need scaling, not the entire app package.